# How to export dynamic gridview data to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have created dynamic grid for report and kept an option as export to excel. I used html Render-Control to export but my problem is when i tried to export in excel, i am getting blank excel sheet. Any one can you please help me. Thanks in advance

```
Response.Clear();
        string date_only_for_excel = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        string FileName = "REPORT_" + date_only_for_excel + ".xls";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + "");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);



        htmlWrite.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='24'></td></tr>");
        htmlWrite.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='24'></td></tr>");
        //htmlWrite.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='24' style='text-align:left;font-size:22;color:#f79646;margin-left:100px;'>BOQ REPORT</td></tr>");
        htmlWrite.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='24'></td></tr>");
        htmlWrite.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='24'></td></tr>");
        htmlWrite.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='24'></td></tr>");
        Div2.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

I have created dynamic grid and added to this panel

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Export_Panel" runat="server">
                </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: update your code in ur question

Comment: If i place my grid control in aspx page means, it's working fine. I have used same code for static grid but while dynamic i am getting blank in excel

Comment: Is their any possible to export without re-binding the grid data

Answer (score 0):

use  `gridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);`   instead   of

```
Div2.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
```

Comment: id will be generated dynamically, i have multiple grids depends op-on data. So, i can't place gridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
protected void ExportToExcel(GridView gv)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=YourFileName.xls");

        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            //To Export all pages
            gv.AllowPaging = false;
            gv.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in gv.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                cell.BackColor = gv.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
            {
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex%2 == 0)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = gv.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = gv.RowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }

            gv.RenderControl(hw);

            //style to format numbers to string
            var style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Debug your code and see if your grid view contain any data !

Comment: While exporting , now getting like this ** <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Export_Panel" Class="docbody" style="margin-bottom: 20px; width: 2015px;">** what i have missed out

Comment: Update your HTML in question.

Comment: I got the solution. Just converted all the grid rows into table cells. And used that table for export. thanks for you support friends.